# PDF link and accessibility -- download yes or no?

Tags: html, pdf, hyperlink, accessibility

I'm creating a site with downloadable PDF links in which we add a parameter at the end of the file download URL to tell the browser how to serve up the file:

```
https://example.com?ref=0&download=y
```

Using the parameter `download=y` opens the browser's file download dialog, asking the user to save the file to their desktop so they can open it with their machine's default PDF viewer.

Using `download=n` will open the browser's built-in PDF viewer, allowing the user to read the PDF without saving it to their machine.

I'm trying to understand which approach is more accessible for mobile / desktop / users with disabilities. Is one approach inherently better than the other from an accessibility perspective?

Answer (score 2):

You could always let the user decide.  If your link went directly to a PDF, then the user can change their browser settings to either view the PDF within the browser or to use an external viewer.  I much prefer that over the web developer trying to choose for me (no offense).  Personally, I like to view the PDF externally in Acrobat because the screen reader handles the PDF pretty well **if** the PDF is tagged.  If you don't have a [tagged PDF](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/create-verify-pdf-accessibility.html), then it won't matter how you serve up the file because the visually impaired user will have a tough time reading it.

Comment: Thanks for your response -- I agree with you in principle, which is why I go with `download=n`, which does not automatically download the file by default, but opens it first in the browser viewer and gives the user a button to download the file if they prefer to read in a desktop viewer. Yes it's two steps, but it provides greater choice. 

Maybe I should mention that I'm working in a CMS that (I think) *requires* us to choose between `y` or `n`. The file is served from a CDN (Akamai) that gives an error if we don't append `?ref=0` to the hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

Letting the user decide is the correct approach. This isn't a setting that you should be attempting to configure for accessibilty purposes.

Having properly tagged PDF documents is vastly more important.

It's also good practice that any HTML links to PDF documents be labeled as such in the anchor text.

e.g. `<a href="foo.pdf">Title of Document (PDF)</a>`

Comment: Does anyone have any links to "official" web-accessibility documentation that support the claim "any HTML links to PDF documents be labeled as such"?

Comment: It's not a requirement to achieve compliance with WCAG, but rather more of a best-practice that will increase the usefulness of your content for all visitors, regardless of ability level.

Comment: "Many users prefer to know the file type when opening a file that results in opening a new application to view the file, so it is often regarded as useful to include this additional information. However, this is not required for compliance with this success criterion"
https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/html/H30#example-6